# PermissionError: [WinError 32] with os.remove

Tags: python, operating-system, ocr

I'm trying to set up the [kraken](https://kraken.re/main/index.html) OCR.
The setup run but once the processing is complete, i run into the following error:
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Here is the code:

```
@cli.result_callback()
def process_pipeline(subcommands, input, batch_input, suffix, **args):
    """
    Helper function calling the partials returned by each subcommand and
    placing their respective outputs in temporary files.
    """
    import glob
    import tempfile

    input = list(input)
    if batch_input and suffix:
        for batch_expr in batch_input:
            for in_file in glob.glob(batch_expr, recursive=True):
                input.append((in_file, '{}{}'.format(os.path.splitext(in_file)[0], suffix)))

    for io_pair in input:
        try:
            base_image = io_pair[0]
            fc = [io_pair[0]] + [tempfile.mkstemp()[1] for cmd in subcommands[1:]] + [io_pair[1]] 
            for task, input, output in zip(subcommands, fc, fc[1:]):
                    task(base_image=base_image, input=input, output=output)
                    base_image = input
        finally:
            for f in fc[1:-1]:
                os.remove(f)
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\nilsm\Documents\Evora\Anne\.venv\Scripts\kraken.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\nilsm\Documents\Evora\Anne\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nilsm\Documents\Evora\Anne\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nilsm\Documents\Evora\Anne\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1689, in invoke
    return _process_result(rv)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nilsm\Documents\Evora\Anne\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1626, in _process_result
    value = ctx.invoke(self._result_callback, value, **ctx.params)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nilsm\Documents\Evora\Anne\.venv\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nilsm\Documents\Evora\Anne\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kraken\kraken.py", line 229, in process_pipeline
    os.remove(f)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] Le processus ne peut pas accéder au fichier car ce fichier est utilisé par un autre processus: 'C:\\Users\\nilsm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp0y01ohqn'
```

I understand that I should close the file before removing it but I do not fully understand the way the source code manage to open and store these files. Thus I am not able to close said files.

I understood by doing some research that the source code should correctly run on Linux since the os module allows Linux to close a file that is open but not on Windows. Unfortunatly I can not migrate on Linux for this project..
How could I allow the code to run?
Thank you

Comment: Kraken doesn't support windows.

Comment: Dear @Jahan, I understand that. However my friend is not able to use Linux and need OCR for his history master. That's the reason why I'm trying to twist the source code. So far, it's the last change I have to make in order to make kraken compile properly.